# Wrong number or types in call of a sproc

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I keep getting this stored procedure error (wrong number or types of the arguments) whenever I try to execute it from C#.

here's the definition of variables for the sproc:

```
requestNumber varchar2,
requestXML clob,
userID varchar2,
activityID integer,
origin_zip varchar2,
destination_zip varchar2,
pur_date varchar2
```

and here's the definition of the oracle parameteres inside the C# code:

```
OracleParameter _requestNumber = new OracleParameter("requestNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = requestNumber };

OracleParameter _requestXML = new OracleParameter("requestXML", OracleDbType.Clob) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = xml };

OracleParameter _userID = new OracleParameter("userID", OracleDbType.Varchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = input.UserID };

OracleParameter _activityID = new OracleParameter("activityID", OracleDbType.Int32) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = Convert.ToInt32(activityID) };

OracleParameter _sOriginZip = new OracleParameter("origin_zip", OracleDbType.Varchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = _originZip };

OracleParameter _sDestinationZip = new OracleParameter("destination_zip", OracleDbType.Varchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = _destinationZIP };

OracleParameter _sPurDate = new OracleParameter("pur_date", OracleDbType.Varchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = _purDate };

                command.Parameters.Add(_requestNumber);
                command.Parameters.Add(_requestXML);
                command.Parameters.Add(_userID );
                command.Parameters.Add(_activityID );
                command.Parameters.Add( _sOriginZip);
                command.Parameters.Add( _sDestinationZip);
                command.Parameters.Add( _sPurDate);
```

What could be causing that exception?

Comment: You might want to include the actual calling of the procedure too (eg the construction and settings on the command object) in case the error is in there...

Comment: Why not do some more debugging to hone in on the problem? Try temporarily setting each stored proc parameter to "default null", and continually changing your c# to pass just one param each time. When it goes bang, that's the param with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clear command parameters using following code before adding parameters,

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
```

Also check are you setting, `command.Type` to storedProcedure